# Is it Malicious php Code? php.var.function.14

Tags: php

I scanned my site with WP Antivirus Site Protection and found an infected file.

This file is a main file in my site template.

> Malware Type: php.var.function.14

Is this malicious code? If so, please suggest how to prevent the malicious activity.

Can anyone, please, advise what this php code will do?

Here is the code:

```html
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_header_adv_page' );
function register_header_adv_page(){
    add_submenu_page(  'wb_add_adv','wb_header_adv', 'تبلیغات هدر', 'manage_options', 'wb_header_adv','wb_header_adv' );
}
//---------------------------------------------------
function wb_header_adv(){
    global $wpdb;
    //------------------------add--------------------
    if(isset($_POST['add_header_btn'])){
        $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if($_POST['H1']=='update'){
            $wpdb->query("update ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv set advid='".$_POST['h1r_adv_id']."', showadv='".$_POST['show_header1']."' where location='H1R'");
           $wpdb->query("update ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv set advid='".$_POST['h1l_adv_id']."',showadv='".$_POST['show_header1']."' where location='H1L'"); 
            
        } else{
            $location="H1R";
             $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv (date,showadv,type,location,advid) values('".$date."','".$_POST['show_header1']."','img','".$location."','".$_POST['h1r_adv_id']."')");
             $location="H1L";
             $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv (date,showadv,type,location,advid) values('".$date."','".$_POST['show_header1']."','img','".$location."','".$_POST['h1l_adv_id']."')");
        }
        
         $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if($_POST['H2']=='update'){
            $wpdb->query("update ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv set advid='".$_POST['h2r_adv_id']."', showadv='".$_POST['show_header2']."' where location='H2R'");
           $wpdb->query("update ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv set advid='".$_POST['h2l_adv_id']."',showadv='".$_POST['show_header2']."' where location='H2L'"); 
            
        } else{
            $location="H2R";
             $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv (date,showadv,type,location,advid) values('".$date."','".$_POST['show_header2']."','img','".$location."','".$_POST['h2r_adv_id']."')");
             $location="H2L";
             $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv (date,showadv,type,location,advid) values('".$date."','".$_POST['show_header2']."','img','".$location."','".$_POST['h2l_adv_id']."')");
        }
        
        $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if($_POST['H3']=='update'){
            if($_POST['h3_type']=="slider"){
                 $advids = serialize($_POST['h3r_adv_id']);
            }else{
                $advids = $_POST['h3r_adv_id'];
            }
            $wpdb->query("update ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv set advid='".$advids."', showadv='".$_POST['show_header3']."',type='".$_POST['h3_type']."' where location='H3R'");
            
        } else{
            $location="H3R";
            if($_POST['h3_type']=="slider"){
                 $advids = serialize($_POST['h3r_adv_id']);
            }else{
                 $advids = $_POST['h3r_adv_id'];
            }
             $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv (date,showadv,type,location,advid) values('".$date."','".$_POST['show_header3']."','".$_POST['h3_type']."','".$location."','".$advids."')");
             
        }
        
    }
    //-----------------------select------------------
        $h1r_adv = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT showadv,advid FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv where location='H1R'");     
    $header1_showadv=$h1r_adv->showadv;
    $h1r_id=$h1r_adv->advid; 
//------------    
     $h1l_adv = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT showadv,advid FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv where location='H1L'"); 
    $h1l_id=$h1l_adv->advid;
//----------
        $h2r_adv = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT showadv,advid FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv where location='H2R'");     
    $header2_showadv=$h2r_adv->showadv;
    $h2r_id=$h2r_adv->advid; 
//------------    
     $h2l_adv = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT showadv,advid FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv where location='H2L'"); 
    $h2l_id=$h2l_adv->advid;
//----------
            $h3r_adv = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT showadv,advid,type FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."softadv where location='H3R'");     
    $header3_showadv=$h3r_adv->showadv;
    $h3r_id=$h3r_adv->advid;
     $h3r_type=$h3r_adv->type; 
//------------ 
    

?>
    <h3>پلن 1</h3>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                     <label><input type="checkbox" name="show_header1" value="1" <?php if($header1_showadv) echo 'checked'; ?> />نمایش</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    تبلیغات سمت راست : 
                </td>
                <td>
                    
                    <select name="h1r_adv_id">
                        <option>انتخاب تبلیغ</option>
                        <?php show_img_adv_list_in_select('header',$h1r_id,'img') ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    تبلیغات سمت چپ : 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="h1l_adv_id">
                        <option>انتخاب تبلیغ</option>
                        <?php show_img_adv_list_in_select('header',$h1l_id,'img') ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
        <h3>پلن 2</h3>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                     <label><input type="checkbox" name="show_header2" value="1" <?php if($header2_showadv) echo 'checked'; ?> />نمایش</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    تبلیغات سمت راست : 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select  name="h2r_adv_id">
                        <option>انتخاب تبلیغ</option>
                        <?php show_img_adv_list_in_select('header',$h2r_id,'img') ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    تبلیغات سمت چپ : 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select  name="h2l_adv_id">
                        <option value="">انتخاب تبلیغ</option>
                        <?php show_img_adv_list_in_select('header',$h2l_id,'img') ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
        <h3>پلن 3</h3>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                     <label><input type="checkbox" name="show_header3" value="1" <?php if($header3_showadv) echo 'checked'; ?> />نمایش</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <select name="h3_type" class="h3_type">
                        <option <?php if($h3r_type=="img") echo "selected"; ?> value="img">بنر</option>
                        <option <?php if($h3r_type=="slider") echo "selected"; ?> value="slider">اسلایدر</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    تبلیغات سمت راست : 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select <?php if($h3r_type=="slider"){ echo 'name="h3r_adv_id[]" multiple';} else if($h3r_type=="img") echo 'name="h3r_adv_id"'; ?>  class="h3r_adv_id">
                        <option>انتخاب تبلیغ</option>
                        <?php show_img_adv_list_in_select('header',$h3r_id,$h3r_type) ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="ذخیره" name="add_header_btn" class="button-primary add_h_adv_btn" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php if ( null !== $h1r_adv ) { echo "update"; } ?>" name="H1" />
        
         <input type="hidden" value="<?php if ( null !== $h2r_adv ) { echo "update"; } ?>" name="H2" />
       
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php if ( null !== $h3r_adv ) { echo "update"; } ?>" name="H3" />
    </form>
<?php
}
//--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: And row 14 is? We don’t see row numbers

Comment: I think the danger/maliciousness of this code depends on whether or not ```$wpdb``` escapes what is placed in ```$_POST['h1l_adv_id']```.

Comment: row 14 or function.14 ??